# this.$refs.name.select() function not found in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue refs in my application so that in click a button some text will be select and copy. So I am using like

```
//In template
<input type="text" ref="url" value="my url"/>
<button @click="copylink">Copy Link</button>


//in methods
copylink() {
    this.$refs.url.select()
}
```

that is undefined.

But Using

```
document.querySelector('input').select()
```

I can select that.

My question is it possible all document methods using $refs. How do you do this?

Comment: You need to post your component code for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: Your snippet works ([proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/o4Lw9gx6/)). Please add some details to help us to reproduce your issue or add a live example (fiddle/codepen...)

Answer (score 1):

If you do console.log(this.$refs.url) it will give you back an array type result. All you have to do is: this.$refs.url[0].select() and it will work.

Let me know.